# Laravel Homestead Box 0.4.2 uses php5.6 instead of php7

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead, php-7

I have a small problem. Rather I hope its a small problem:
Two days ago I installed a homestead box with `vagrant box add laravel/homestead` and with `composer global require "laravel/homestead=~2.0"`.

Now I have box version 0.4.2 and Homestead version 2.2.1 but I only have php5.6 available. I want php7. I haven't changed anything in my config. The curious thing is that on my mac homestead runs with php7 with the same installation procedure.

Any ideas how to solve this? Everytime I google about it the only questions I find are about to downgrade to php5.6 from php7. Some answers on laracast only says that php7 is the default version in newer vagrant boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just upgrade your Homestead box. I've made new installation few days ago and current PHP version is 7.0.3 there.

Also, you could just connect to the box with SSH (or `vagrant ssh` command) and add repository and remove PHP 5:

```
sudo apt-get install -y language-pack-en-base
sudo LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge php5-common -y
```

And then install PHP 7:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-fpm php7.0-mysql -y
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove -y
```

Alternative manual: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:
I had 2 different versions of homestead installed.
The 0.4.2 and a 0.3.? version. I solved the problem by removing the vagrant boxes & by deleting my homestead configs and reinstalling the homestead composer package. After that I reinstalled the vagrant box and everything works fine now.